# Android Studio resolve dependencies

Tags: android, android-studio

Still fighting Android Studio and gradle... I have downloaded an open source project The build.gradle file in the app has for example this code

```
compile 'dnsjava:dnsjava:2.1.7'
```

The dnsjava.jar file does not come with the project, but I have downloaded the jar file from the provider. Where do I have to place this jar file now to remove this error due to a missing dependency?

Comment: The whole idea of gradle is that you don't have to download the jar, gradle does this for you.

Comment: https://github.com/adamfisk/LittleProxy/issues/27 dnsjava is not on maven central, you have to add the repository to your build file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole idea of gradle is that you don't have to download the jar, gradle does this for you.

If Gradle can't resolve the dependency, you should remove that dependency and add the exact location of the jar in your project to the build file, for instance like this:

```
dependencies {
    compile files('src/main/libs/dnsjava.jar')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to download and save it local. Just compile the project and gradle will autodownload and compile it for you. Just try

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the real idea of using the gradle to avoid downloading the jar, if you *have to* download the jar , create folder *libs* where your **src** is, place the jar in **libs** folder .
Add following lines to your **build.gradle** , like

```
dependencies {
        compile files('libs/dnsjava:dnsjava:2.1.7.jar')  
}
```